# My sql select that has multiple row in the same criteria

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table like this

[image]

I want to get row that has minimum 2 or more than 2 (multiple) row only from this table, so the result would be like this

[image]

What do i do?

thank you

Comment: Can you clarify based on what field you want to select? In your example it seems as if you want to select all `cust_id` that occur more than once, but as id `02.053.086` appears twice in your example output, it is not entirely clear what your exact criteria are.

Comment: @soimon Im sorry, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses

```sql
SELECT t.* FROM my_table t
JOIN (
  SELECT cust_id, MIN(transaction_no) AS transaction_no
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY cust_id
  HAVING COUNT(cust_id) > 1
) agg ON t.transaction_no = agg.transaction_no
```